# How common or universal this definition of abolute value, module of "norm"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces, absolute-value

In complex numbers the module can be defined as

$$|z|=\exp(\Re(\ln z))$$

I wonder, to what extent a similar value is useful/used/meaningful in other rings?
I mean, instead of taking the real part $\Re$ one may use trace or other means of obtaining the "real part" of an object. Does it still hold meaningful?

What if it turns out that $|z|<\Re (z)$ in some field? Obviously, the Pythagorean theorem gets broken and such "module" cannot be a norm, but otherwise, what properties does it still keep?

Comment: What does $\ln$ mean in an arbitrary ring? What about $\exp$? Or $\Re$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos exp is the exponential function, generalized by power series, $\Re$ may be replaced with trace or other operators that oftain vaguely "real part" of the element of the ring.

Comment: Read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm . It is a purely algebraical construction, no need to involve analysis. Basically, the ordinary definition of the norm comes from the extension $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$ of degree $2$ and every norm is $N(z)=z\overline{z}=|z|^2$. (You don't get $|z|$ but $|z|^2$, but this often does not make a load of difference and is easier to manipulate.)